Word, number and letter
Revelation occurs in stages so investigation may be required for this.
Account for each of the following numbers:

789629
1034
150
1034
186
3
178
10
198
2
1184
29913
22

Once the counts are explained, say what is special about the sum when all factors are taken into account.

It's nothing to do with lateral thinking or a treasure hunt where one clue leads to another. It's just a strangely worded math question.

rot13(Gur fhz vf $frira^{frira}$)

@Nautilus You haven't accounted for any of the numbers individually. If you assume there is nothing more than what you have found and then complain the question is wrong, perhaps question your assumption.

@Nautilus I adjusting the wording in response to your comment.

This is a collection of numbers associated with

 Word, number, and letter counts in the KJV Bible, as alluded by the mention of "Revelation". The presumed intention is to account for every printed word/letter/number in the Bible and find the sum.


 There is a bit of discrepancy on some counts depending on the specific version and method of counting, but here is an explanation of these particular figures and a source:

 789629: base words in the KJV bible
 1034: superscription numbers in Psalms (the remaining facts use this same source)
 150: total times the word "PSALM" is listed
 1034: total times the word "Chapter" is listed
 186: words in the epistle postscripts
 3: words in "King James Version" (on cover)
 178: words in OT book names
 10: # of commandments ? Or more likely 10 more words found in the text not yet counted, including "The New Testament", "The Old Testament", "Table of Contents" and maybe "Authorized"
 198: words in NT book names
 2: words in "Holy Bible" (on cover)
 1184: This is the # of chapters in the bible (1189) minus the # of books with only one chapter (5) where chapters are not listed, so this seems to be the # of listed chapter numbers in books with chapters
 29913: this is exactly the # of verses (31102) minus the number of chapters (1189). Since the first verse of each chapter is not numbered, this looks to be the # of printed verse numbers
 22:  words in the Psalm 119 acrostic

As mentioned in the comments, these sum to

 823,543, which is exactly 7 raised to the 7th power. This is special given the theme of the numbers selected in that in the Bible, seven is a significant number, considered the number of "perfection" or "completion".  When the numbers result in this sum (albeit somewhat forced), it is often referred to as the "Elton Anomaly".


Very close except for 3+10+2. But +1 anyway.
